# Grails one to many relationship Error

Tags: grails, associations, unique

I have a User domain Class as follows:

```
package xyz

class User {
    String login
    String password
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String address
    String email
    static hasMany = [
        websites: AddWebsite
    ]
    static constraints = {
        login blank:false, size:5..15,matches:/[\S]+/, unique:true
        password blank:false, size:5..15,matches:/[\S]+/
        firstName blank:false
        lastName blank:false
        email email: true

    }
}
```

and another AddWebsite domain class as follows:

```
package xyz
import xyz.User;
class AddWebsite {

    String website
    User user
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
    static constraints = { website url:true }
}
```

I am working with MongoDB at the backend. I need that every user who logs in can add websites but a user can't add same websites multiple times but same website can be added by different users. Whenever I try to add a website, it shows me "user cannot be null error".

My controller class for AddWebsite is as follows:

```
package xyz

class AddWebsiteController {

    def index() {
    }
def addWebsites() {
    if(request.method == 'POST') {
        def u = new AddWebsite()
        u.properties[
                    'website'
                ] = params

        if(u.website =="" ) {
            u.errors.rejectValue("website", "addwebsite.website.empty")
            return [addWebsite:u]
        }
        else if(u.save()) {
            render view:'addWebsites', model:[message: "Successfully saved: \""+u.website+"\" Add more websites..."]
            //redirect(controller: "AddWebsite", action: "websiteAdded")

        }
        else {
            return [addWebsite:u]
        }
    }
}


def websiteAdded() {
}

def failed(){
}
```

}

Also, I am not sure how to test whether this one to many association. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I made this change in the controller so that the user won't be null anymore:

```
def addWebsites() {
    if(request.method == 'POST') {
        def w = new AddWebsite()
        w.properties[
                    'website'
                ] = params
        w.user = session["user"]   //modified
        if(w.website =="" ) {
            w.errors.rejectValue("website", "addwebsite.website.empty")
            return [addWebsite:w]
        }
        else if(w.save()) {
            render view:'addWebsites', model:[message: "Successfully saved: \""+w.website+"\" Add more websites..."]
        }
        else {
            return [addWebsite:w]
        }
    }
}
```